# Books about Android User Interface design

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

In my opinions, a beautiful UI is extrem important for the success of app.

So now I'm searching a book about the User Interface design (at best) for Android, it should not be about the technical implementation, like how to create a menu or use different layouts. It should be more about the design concept.

The offical document: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html is great, but too short. I also found a book exact about this topic, but it's still not yet published until 2013.

So any suggestion about books in this topic would be thankful.

Comment: This book is very interesting (excerpts of it on this website): [Android Design Patterns: Interaction Design Solutions for Developers](http://www.androiddesignbook.com/). It compares Android design a lot with iOS. The full book is also available as an ebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this link, here you can find nice tutorial and its description .

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/

[Conference Coverage about Android and User Interface Design on Lanyrd](http://lanyrd.com/coverage/?topics=android,user-interface-design)

Comment: Can you give us any latest resources? I think many thing have changed.

Comment: @Imon Please check this link - http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[Juhani Lehtimaki's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118387287) seems to be the one you're looking for. He is the author of [Android UI Patterns](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html) blog, but his book is not released yet (October).

Answer (score 1):

You can also buy Neil Davies's new book Android UI in action..this book has a lot of great stuff on UI and UX...check this out: http://www.manning.com/davies/

Comment: but it's still under writing right? I can only get this book in 2013?

Comment: yes..but its worth waiting for.I have read the first chapter and found it very informative..Its available on the above link

Comment: Just checked the website, they say: _We regret that Manning Publications will not be publishing this title_.